# Undefined variable in php even after i assign logic to get its value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a simple logic to sort and assign a label to it

but sometimes `Undefined variable` : `predikat_cluster2` error is shown

Can you point out my mistake? my apologies for asking trivial stuff like this but I'm very new at this

Thank you in advance.

```
    $rata_rata1 = '';
    $rata_rata2 = '';
    $rata_rata3 = '';
    $predikat_cluster1 ='';
    $predikat_cluster2 ='';
    $predikat_cluster3 ='';

            foreach($centroidcluster->result() as $h)
            {    

    $rata_rata1 = $h->centroid1cluster1_baru;


    $rata_rata2 = $h->centroid1cluster2_baru; 

    $rata_rata3 = $h->centroid1cluster3_baru;

  }
    ////PREDIKAT CENTROID 1

    if($rata_rata1 > $rata_rata2&& $rata_rata1 > $rata_rata3){
      $predikat_cluster1 = "Sangat Baik";
    }
    elseif($rata_rata1> $rata_rata2&& $rata_rata1 < $rata_rata3)
    {
      $predikat_cluster1 = "Baik";
    }
     elseif($rata_rata1 < $rata_rata2&& $rata_rata1 < $rata_rata3)
    {
      $predikat_cluster1 = "Cukup Baik";
    }


    if($rata_rata2 > $rata_rata3&& $rata_rata2 > $rata_rata1){
      $predikat_cluster2 = "Sangat Baik";
    }
    elseif($rata_rata2> $rata_rata3&& $rata_rata2 < $rata_rata1)
    {
      $predikat_cluster2 = "Baik";
    }
     elseif($rata_rata2 < $rata_rata3&& $rata_rata2 < $rata_rata1)
    {
      $predikat_cluster2 = "Cukup Baik";
    }

    if($rata_rata3 > $rata_rata2&& $rata_rata3 > $rata_rata1){
      $predikat_cluster3 = "Sangat Baik";
    }
    elseif($rata_rata3 > $rata_rata2&& $rata_rata3 < $rata_rata1)
    {
      $predikat_cluster3 = "Baik";
    }
    elseif($rata_rata3 < $rata_rata2&& $rata_rata3 < $rata_rata1)
    {
      $predikat_cluster3 = "Cukup Baik";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: best is define variables before all if else sentences ... :)

Comment: I think the error is generated when you are trying to use the variable that is not created. can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the complete and exact error message you are getting.